# Conjectures on perfect squares

Tags: nt.number-theory

There exist **infinitely** many sets of three **positive integers** $(a,b,c)$ where $a\not=b,b\not=c$ and $c\not=a$ such that each of $$ab-1,\ bc-1,\ ca-1,\ ab-a-b+c,\ bc-b-c+a,\ ca-c-a+b$$
is a **perfect square** (note that $0=0^2$ is a perfect square). For example, for $$(a,b,c)=(F_{2n-1},F_{2n+1},F_{2n+3})$$
where $F_k$ is the $k$-th Fibonacci number defined by $F_0=0,F_1=1,F_{k}=F_{k-2}+F_{k-1}\ (k\ge 2)$,  we have
$${ab-1}={{F_{2n}}^2},\ {bc-1}={F_{2n+2}}^2,\ {ca-1}={F_{2n+1}}^2$$ 
$${ab-a-b+c}={(F_{2n}+1)^2},{bc-b-c+a}={(F_{2n+2}-1)^2},ca-c-a+b={(F_{2n+1}-1)^2}.$$

By the way, I noticed that for *every such set* $(a,b,c)$ *I found*, each of 
$$ab+a+b-c,\ bc+b+c-a,\ ca+c+a-b$$
is also a perfect square.

For example, for $(a,b,c)=(F_{2n-1},F_{2n+1},F_{2n+3})$, we have
$${ab+a+b-c}={(F_{2n}-1)^2},{bc+b+c-a}={(F_{2n+2}+1)^2},{ca+c+a-b}={(F_{2n+1}+1)^2}.$$

So, I asked if proposition 1 is true on [math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1134694/if-ab-1-bc-1-ca-1-ab-a-bc-bc-b-ca-ca-c-ab-are-perfect-squares-then-are-ab) and knew that it is false.

**Proposition 1 (False)** : For positive integers $(a,b,c)$ such that $a\not=b,b\not=c$ and $c\not=a$, if each of $$ab-1,\ bc-1,\ ca-1,\ ab-a-b+c,\ bc-b-c+a,\ ca-c-a+b$$
is a perfect square, then each of
$$ab+a+b-c,\ bc+b+c-a,\ ca+c+a-b$$
is a perfect square.

Every counterexample for proposition 1 found on math.SE satisfies
$$a=1\ \ \text{and}\ \ ab+a+b-c\lt 0$$
such as 
$$(a,b,c)=(1,5,65),(1,2,145),(1,10,325).$$

Then, I asked the following question on math.SE, but I have not received any complete answers.

> **Question** : Are the following propositions true?
>
> **Proposition 2 (True)** : For positive integers $(a,b,c)$ such that $\color{red}{1\le} a\lt b\lt c$ and $ab+a+b-c\ge 0$, if each of $$ab-1,\ bc-1,\ ca-1,\ ab-a-b+c,\ bc-b-c+a,\ ca-c-a+b$$
>   is a perfect square, then each of
>   $$ab+a+b-c,\ bc+b+c-a,\ ca+c+a-b$$
>   is a perfect square.
>
> **Proposition 3** : For positive integers $(a,b,c)$ such that $\color{red}{2\le} a\lt b\lt c$, if each of $$ab-1,\ bc-1,\ ca-1,\ ab-a-b+c,\ bc-b-c+a,\ ca-c-a+b$$
>   is a perfect square, then each of
>   $$ab+a+b-c,\ bc+b+c-a,\ ca+c+a-b$$
>   is a perfect square.
>
> **Proposition 4 (True)** : For positive integers $(a,b,c)$ such that $\color{red}{1\le} a\lt b\lt c$, if each of $$ab-1,\ bc-1,\ ca-1,\ ab\mp (a+ b-c),\ bc\mp (b+ c- a),\ ca\mp (c+ a-b)$$
>   is a perfect square, then $c=a+b+2\sqrt{ab-1}$ holds.

I would like to know if these propositions are true and any relevant references.

**Additional information** : On math.SE, a user Tito Piezas III found that if
$$ab-1 = d^2,\ \ c = a + b - 2 d,$$
then
$$\begin{aligned}
a b-1\; &= d^2\\ 
a c-1\; &= (a - d)^2\\
b c-1 \; &=  (b - d)^2\\ 
a b - a - b + c \; &=  (1 - d)^2\\
b c + a - b - c  \; &=  (1 - b + d)^2\\ 
a c - a + b - c  \; &=  (1 - a + d)^2\\ 
a b +  a + b - c \; &=  (1 + d)^2\\ 
b c - a + b + c \; &=  (1 + b - d)^2\\ 
a c + a - b + c \; &=  (1 + a - d)^2
.\end{aligned}$$

The proposition 4 comes from Tito Piezas III's findings.

**Added** : From duje's comment, we can say

> If each of
>   $$ab-1,\ \ bc-1,\ \ ca-1$$
>   is a perfect square and $0\lt a\lt b\lt c\lt 3ab\in\mathbb Z$, then $c=a+b+2\sqrt{ab-1}$ holds.

By adding Tito Piezas III's findings to this result, we can say

> If each of
>   $$ab-1,\ \ bc-1,\ \ ca-1$$
>   is a perfect square and $0\lt a\lt b\lt c\lt 3ab\in\mathbb Z$, then each of $$ab\mp (a+ b-c),\ bc\mp (b+ c- a),\ ca\mp (c+ a-b)$$
>   is a perfect square.

**Added** : A user duje pointed that since $1\le a\lt b\lt c,ab+a+b-c\ge 0\Rightarrow c\lt 3ab,$ we can say that proposition 2 and 4 are true.

Comment: By Lemma 7 from http://web.math.pmf.unizg.hr/~duje/pdf/dioeul2.pdf if c<3ab, then c=a+b+2*sqrt(ab-1).

Comment: @duje: Thank you so much. The result is close to my question.

Comment: @mathlove Note that if c>3ab, then ab+a+b-c<0, so it cannot be a perfect square. So I think that this settles Propositions 2 and 4.

Comment: @duje: You are right! Thank you so much.